# How to convert string variable to namespace object

Tags: javascript, object, namespaces

I have a javascript service `CoreAdapterService`. Within that code there are a lot of literal references to `CoreAdapterService` namespace which I want to replace with a `var`.

I have tried declaring a `var` at the top of the service and use it in the service as shown in code sample but no luck. Any help welcome

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry it seems like my previous answer was incorrect, you are currently trying to get a var inside your object. The function you are executing has another scope so it is unable to reach the variable. A possible solution would be to define your variable above your adapter. Then the following code should work.

Try the following:

```
var definition = this[adapterNameSpace].service[service];
```

This way you are gettings this.CoreAdapterService.services[service];

Comment: it should be `this[this.adapterNameSpace].service[service]`